# time.sleep function hiding text until KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, sleep

When I use `sleep` in `while True` it's showing nothing until I do keyboard interrupt.

Here's my code:

```
from colorama import Back
from time import sleep
while True:
    print(Back.RED +'Lol' ,sep=" " ,end=" ")
    sleep(0.2)
```

Output:

```
 |py
 |c:/.../colograma.py
 |
```

It's empty...

When I do Ctrl-C it shows this:

```
Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Lol Traceback 
 (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/blabl/Desktop/LukaOzbijan/colograma.py", line 5, in 
 <module>
        sleep(0.2)
        KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Is the problem the same when you don't use colorama?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output is buffered, and nothing is actually written to standard output until the buffer fills up. Add `flush=True` to output text immediately.

```
print(Back.RED + 'Lol', end=" ", flush=True)
```

(`sep` isn't needed because you only have one string being written per call to `print`.)